# Listener for activity finish from outside the class

Tags: android

I have a singleton class whose one of the methods accepts source activity class name and destination activity class name.

```
Public void handleActivityTransition(Activity srcActivity, String destActivity){

 srcActivity.startActivity(new intent (srcActivity
```

, destActivity)) ;

}

This method basically starts the destination activity. However this method/class needs to do an operation when the destination activity is destroyed/finished  (for example back button or some other action).

The way I am solving it as that I am overwriting the on destroy method of the destination activity and calling the method on the singleton class. However I feel that this is bad approach. Is there a listener or some other way to know when the destination activity is destroyed from the singleton class above.

Thanks

Comment: already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785806/android-how-to-make-an-activity-return-results-to-the-activity-which-calls-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like all you have to do is start the Intent by startActivityForResult() 
and then pass the requestCode on the basis of the combination you are trying to achieve.

And then finally you can do whatever task you want to do in the onActivityResult() of the source Activity according to the request code you made earlier.

I don't really see the use of a Singleton here. Can create any combination from the source itself. But you can implement this in the singleton too if you want with some effort. Though it would be much easier to do it in the source Activity itself.

Comment: Thank u. The problem with that is that inactivityresult is called on the source and I want the singleton to be the one doing the work. Yea i know this is not the best thing but I have reasons for using singleton in this case

Comment: Well then have a dummy activity do this work each time. A dummy activity with no layout or anything. It would solve the problem. Instead of a singleton use a dummy activity as a singleton which u always keep a single copy of. Or much better a fragment. A fragment without a UI. From there you can do it easily.

Comment: You can actually leak an activity to your advantage. Leak the activity so that it always remain alive and then do whatever you wanted to with the singleton in that activity.

Comment: Interesting idea. I will look into that. Thx alot

Comment: Yes. Tell me if it works so that I can put an answer down.