# What pattern to use to update data in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have two activities "A" and "B". In "A" I have a RecyclerView and an "add" btn.
After I press "add" new "activity B" via "startActivityForResult" opens. I fill fields in "B" -> press save btn -> starts new "AsyncTask" in which I add new element to my database.
[image]
And the question is how to update RecyclerView data in "A activity" the right way?

I'm not providing code because I would like to hear the answer in general how to build my app architecture.

Comment: read about `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how to make an activity return results to the activity which calls it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785806/android-how-to-make-an-activity-return-results-to-the-activity-which-calls-it)

Comment: Yes I know about startActivityForResult. The question is how to update data in "acitivity A" when i'll insert new data in db, I do it asynchronously so i can call onActivityResult earlier than asyncTask will finish it's job

Answer (score 0):

After activity B is closed and you get the result you must update the recyclerview adapter with the new data again and call notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Yes, but it's not 100% that my asyncTask wil finish it work when i'll call for update from A activity

Comment: you can use EventBus which is a powerful and easy implementation of publisher subscriber pattern to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

In case you created your own subclass of ContentProvider you can call `notifyChange` in function `insert` in this way:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```