# Deep-linking - how to?

Tags: android, deep-linking, deeplink

I am developing an e-commerce android application. Consider **App B** is my app. And in **App B** we have a wallet to pay for the things. Now the requirement is, there is some other app consider **App A** is trying to pay with **App B** using Deeplink.

```
Uri myAction = Uri.parse("myapp://open/myAction?name=" + name + "~" + Phone + "~" + Email);
 Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myAction);
 PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
 List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities (mapIntent, 0);
 boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
if (isIntentSafe) {
    startActivityForResult(mapIntent, 101);
            }
```

By this way, I am calling **App B**

after completing the payment in **App B** I moved to **App A**. How to achieve this one from **App B**

for clear info look at the image

[image]

Thanks in advance for the timing help.

Comment: Quesion is, are you developing the app which will handle the payment or the app which will consume payments app or both?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My App has payment. Some other app trying to pay with my app using deep-link. after successful payment how can i redirect to their app. In the above image App B is my app

Comment: I Jus edited my question for clear understanding. Please look at this. Thanks @MohammedAtif

Comment: If you are using like `startActivityForResult(mapIntent, 101)` when calling the other app then expect that you are waiting for the result inside `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`, check if the return `requestCode` is equal to the one that you've provided in calling the other app/intent then check also if the `resultCode` is `OK` or `Cancelled`.

Comment: Ok let me check on this. Thanks for the advice_/\_

Comment: @MuthuS Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785806/android-how-to-make-an-activity-return-results-to-the-activity-which-calls-it), here is how you return the result from your activity after processing the payment.

Comment: @MohammedAtif Yes, but in my case Open a app's payment screen from another app. So startActivityResult is workout? Sorry for the trouble. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Yes it works. You can start activity for result from other app using deeplink. Please check PayTM or PayU APIs for reference. They will will be great help.

Comment: Yes its working as expected. Thumbs up to you guys.  Thank you so much for your support and advice. @MohammedAtif and and Lester L

Comment: let me create a separate projects and share github here. Thanks all