# Finish all side activities but do not finish the main activity

Tags: java, android

I have this app where the user can open the activites like this:

MainActivity -> ActivityB -> ActivityC -> ActivityD

Now, I want the user to be able to return normally from:

MainActivity <- ActivityB <- ActivityC

Though, if went for ActivityD, I want it to close everything up to the MainActivity:

MainActivity <- ActivityD

Is this the right approach to accomplishing what I want:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14785924/10532911

Edit: I originally thought that /14785924/10532911 applies as a solution. Though, I did not need results at all. The solution below is the one for my case.

Comment: So you are basically asking if an answer of a related stackoverflow-question is working or worth the trouble? *Please*, try it yourself! If it's not working, comment on the question you've just linked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how to make an activity return results to the activity which calls it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785806/android-how-to-make-an-activity-return-results-to-the-activity-which-calls-it)

Comment: user1511417, check my edit. Also, check the solutions below and their comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ActivityD`, to return to `MainActivity`, use a code like this:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Using the flag `CLEAR_TOP` will finish all activities in the stack that are on top of `MainActivity`.

In the example you gave, this will finish `ActivityD`, `ActivityC` and `ActivityB`. Using the flag `SINGLE_TOP` will make sure that this will return control to the existing instance of `MainActivity` (ie: it won't create a new instance of `MainActivity`).

**Edit:**

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

   // place the code above here, to use back button to switch to new activity
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, PradyumanDixit. Though, what is the best place to put the above code. When the user taps back either on ActivityD or navigation bar, I want him to land on MainActivity. Should I put the code above on onDestroy() or should I just start ActivityD with result and when I return to ActivityC, I would carry out the above code? or should I override both <- and navigation bar back and put it there.

Comment: Use this code when you want the user to go back to `MainActivity` from `ActivityD`, if you want to direct them with a button or something like that, then just put this code inside the `onClickListener()` of the button.

Comment: Hi, I am not doing this with a button. I am doing it with the user taps back on either <- or the navigation.

Comment: @Horizon can you try the code in the answer, and tell me if it works as expected or not.

Comment: Yes, placing the code above inside onSupportNavigateUp() and on onBackPressed() works for <- and on navigation. I guess there is no better place to put it. I was kind of hoping I would be able to clear the stack on launching ActivityD and not inside it. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: @Horizon No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is with `Intent` flags like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, Vucko. I cannot pick two answers, sadly. So, I went with the one with more details for future askers.