# "Back Arrow" send data to Parent

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make an application. In my app there is a recycler that contains images, when you click on particualr item it goes to middle activity (that activity gets link to load image(by Picasso) and shows the image), then you can go to the last activity that "*does something*".
But there is a problem in my back arrow thing: 
[image]
The *Last activity* is a child of *Middle activity*, so when you click on the arrow icon it goes to the Middle Activity. BUT *Middle activity* is supposed to get data of image (like link to load image from recycler item). So when the arrow on *LastActivity* is clicked it goes to *MiddleActivity* but doesn't work properly because ***doesn't have the essential link of image.***

It is my click ItemClickListener in my Adapter for recycler:

```js
//IMPLEMENT CLICK LISTENER
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
                String getTitle = mMainList.get(pos).getKeyId();
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),getTitle,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Go to the next Activity
                Intent show_more = new Intent(v.getContext(), MiddleActivity.class);
                show_more.putExtra("image_link", mMainList.get(pos).getImageLink());
                v.getContext().startActivity(show_more);
            }
        });
```

It is intent in MiddleActivity that goes to LastActivity

```js
Intent go_to_last = new Intent(MiddleActivity.this, LastActivity.class);
                        String image_link_push = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_link");
                        go_to_last.putExtra("image_link_push", image_link_push);//push link further
                        startActivity(go_to_last);
```

My thought is that I need to **customize** the *back arrow* and send by intent the image link.
Procces would be looking like this:

*MainAct* (send image link by intent) --- *MiddleAct* (get the link, and send to the next) --- *LastAct* (get the link,on pressed *back arrow* send the same link to Middle) *link would be dragged through all the activities*

I tried to make it by onBackPressed method (in *LastActivity*) but it does nothing:

```js
image_link_back = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_link_push");

 @Override //!!
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LastActivity.this, MiddleActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("image_link_back", image_link_back);
        startActivity(intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
```

Hopefully I have explained my problem correctly.

How can I "customize" the **arrow back** and solve the problem? I would appreciate you answering me.

Comment: why not use StartActivityForResult for your middle activity? then just setResult(link) in your last activity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785806/android-how-to-make-an-activity-return-results-to-the-activity-which-calls-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage startActivityForResult on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when user click arrow back the activity manger closed current activity and launch parent activity so **onCreate** will be called again

**Solution** :
when user click arrow back finish current Activity (LastActivity) without start parentActivity(MiddleActivity) again  by insert this code in **LastActivity**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //listen to back arrow in app bar
            finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly that I need in this particular but yeah it is going to help, thanks.

Comment: @Amazonianpet i know what you want my friend but this code will work with out return url again to middle activity