# Updating comment count for a post in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Activity A has a recycler view, which has each row as a post, now each post has a comment count textview which launches a comment activity where user can see comments and also add comments.

Now question is, after adding a comment how do I update the comment count in that particular row of recycler view in Activity A when comment Activity finishes or pressing back button to get back on posts page. But I don't want to reload the recycler view again as it will distract the user from the current location.

Please guide me in the right direction. Below is my Recyclerview adapter code snippet.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        final Posts posts = postsList.get(position);
        final viewHolderPost viewHolderPost = (viewHolderPost) viewHolder;

        viewHolderPost.commentcount_wrap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), CommentViewerActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("post_id", posts.getPost_id());
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is what I would do:

1. Create common object (preferably Repository), where I would store list of Posts with Comments in memory.
2. When clicking on Post, I would call `startActivityForResult` method from `PostActivity` to open `CommentActivity`
3. After adding/deleting/editing the comment in `CommentActivity` I would update the list in Repository and finish activity with proper result
4. In `PostActivity` I would override `onActivityResult` method to check if the `CommentActivity` finished with result that will tell me to refresh list in RecyclerView
5. If so, I would get the updated list from repository in `PostActivity` and update it in Adapter

Comment: Thanks a lot for the step by step guide. I am currently this process as @Yasu also guided the same thing.

Comment: I have tried this using ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,301); But the problem is I am getting Null as return data in Origin Activity at onActivityResult(). Can you please tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Hey, check this answer, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14785924/2448589

Comment: Hi Mariusz, I have done exactly the same thing except for one difference. I am calling the second activity from RecyclerView.Adapter using ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,301);

Comment: Here is the pastebin code snippet https://pastebin.com/arZDYgxH

Comment: Okay, when you are putting the post_position and comment_count are they Int or String? Because you are trying to read a String in onActivityResult

Comment: I have just used intent.putExtra("comment_count",result_comment_count); I did not specify anything

Comment: But both variables are defined as integer

Comment: Okay, but putExtra is an overloaded method, which means that there are many putExtra methods, which are accepting different parameters. So you need to make sure when you read the data in onActivityResult, you are trying to obtain the same type you put in putExtra

Comment: so you need to call `int commentCount = data.getIntExtra("comment_count", -1);`, where -1 means that the commentCount is not passed/not passed properly from previous activity

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you Mariusz it worked and I got the result.

Comment: Great! :) If everything's fine please accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)

So when the `CommentActivity` is finish, the previous activity will receive a callback that is the result of `CommentActivity`, you will handle that result and update your recyclerview's adapter.

Hope that help. :)

Comment: okay I would give it a try and let you know. thanks @Yasu

Answer (score 0):

You could notify the Adapter that there is a change at the particular position.
check: adapter.notifyItemChanged(1)

-edit-

On your Activity A add this.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if(lastPosition != -1)
        recycler_test.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(lastPosition)
}
```

And your adapter should provide a callback like this.

```
recycler_test.adapter = CustomAdapter(Controller.shared.myList){ positionClicked ->
        //This block of code will be called every time a user clicked a comment.

        lastPosition = positionClicked

        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ActivityB::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("position", positionClicked)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: From where should I call it? Activity A or Comment Activity? Can you please post a code snippet?

Comment: I added some code. Also, instead of onResume you could onActivityResult as the guys have already told you.