How to change the value of a Textview present in another activity if value of Textview in my current Activity changes in Android?
So I have two activities named "MainActivity" and activity named "Second", so my MainActivity has it's own Adapter class named "PractiseAdapter". So my MainActivity contains a Textview with an id
" textCount " and a recyclerview named "recyclerView" and a button "btnGo". The button is used to go to another Activity "Second". So When I click on the Cardview present in the recyclerview my count of "textCount" keeps increasing by 1. Below is the code of my MainActivity.kt
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 private lateinit var textCount:TextView
@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
    textCount = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textCount)
    val btnGo = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnGo)

    val cards = listOf("Item1")


    // Load the saved text count
    loadTextCount()

    val adapter = PractiseAdapter(cards,textCount)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    btnGo.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,Second::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    }

private fun saveTextCount(count: Int) {
    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putInt("textCount", count)
    editor.apply() // or editor.commit()
}

private fun loadTextCount() {
    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val savedCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("textCount", 0)
    textCount.text = savedCount.toString()
}

private fun sendUpdateBroadcast(count: Int) {
    val intent = Intent("com.example.UPDATE_TEXT_COUNT")
    intent.putExtra("textCount", count)
    sendBroadcast(intent)
}


fun updateTextCount(newValue: Int) {
    // Update the TextView
    textCount.text = newValue.toString()
    // Save the new value
    saveTextCount(newValue)
    // Send broadcast
    sendUpdateBroadcast(newValue)
}
}

Below is the code of my adapter class named PractiseAdapter.kt
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class PractiseAdapter(
  private val items:List<String>,
  private val textCount:TextView
):RecyclerView.Adapter<PractiseAdapter.CardViewHolder>() {

private var count=0

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.cardview_item, parent, false)
    return CardViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]
    holder.textView.text = item

    // Optionally set up click listeners or other interactions
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener {
        // Increment the count
        val currentCount = textCount.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
        val newCount = currentCount + 1
        (textCount.context as MainActivity).updateTextCount(newCount)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

class CardViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val cardView: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView1)
    val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName)
}


}

In "Second" Activity, I have a TextView named "textSecondCount", a recyclerview named " recycler1" and a button named "buttonSecond" . textSecond count displays the value of textCount from the MainActivity.kt . There is an Adapter class named SecondAdapter.kt. when I click on the cardview present in it a dialog box pops up like this UI Image as you can see in the dialog box when i click on YES button, subtraction takes place textSecondCount and default value of 10 Textview present in SecondAdapter. And then textSecondCount gets updated with the new value of newCount. Below is the code of my Second Activity
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class Second:AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var textSecondCount:TextView
private lateinit var buttonSecond:Button
private lateinit var recycler1:RecyclerView


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.second)

    textSecondCount = findViewById(R.id.textSecondCount)
    buttonSecond = findViewById(R.id.buttonBack)
    recycler1 = findViewById(R.id.recycler1)


    // Register receiver
    registerReceiver(updateReceiver, IntentFilter("com.example.UPDATE_TEXT_COUNT"),
        RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
    )

    // Load the saved text count
    loadTextCount()

    buttonSecond.setOnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
    }

    val items = listOf("A1")
    val adapter = SecondAdapter(this,items,textSecondCount)
    recycler1.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recycler1.adapter = adapter

}


override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    // Unregister receiver
    unregisterReceiver(updateReceiver)
}

private fun loadTextCount() {
    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val savedCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("textCount", 0)
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textSecondCount).text = savedCount.toString()
}

fun sendUpdateBroadcast(newCount:Int){
    val intent = Intent("com.example.UPDATE_TEXT_COUNT")
    intent.putExtra("textCount", newCount)
    sendBroadcast(intent)
}
private val updateReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val newCount = intent?.getIntExtra("textCount", 0) ?: 0
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textSecondCount).text = newCount.toString()
    }
}
}

Code of it's adapter class is
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class SecondAdapter(
private val context: Context,
private val items: List<String>,
private val textSecondCount: TextView
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SecondAdapter.CardViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.second_adapter, parent, false)
    return CardViewHolder(view)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]
    holder.textViewAdapter.text = holder.textViewAdapter.text

    // Log item value and TextView text
    Log.d("charm", "Item: $item")
    Log.d("charm", "TextView value: ${holder.textViewAdapter.text}")

    holder.cardViewSecond.setOnClickListener {
        // Get the texAdapterCount value for the clicked card
        val textAdapter = holder.textViewAdapter.text.toString()
        val texAdapterCount = textAdapter.toIntOrNull() ?: 0

        // Log the value to check conversion
        Log.d("SecondAdapter", "texAdapterCount: $texAdapterCount")

        showDialog(texAdapterCount)
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun showDialog(texAdapterCount: Int) {
    // Debugging: Log the value of texAdapterCount
    Log.d("SecondAdapter", "texAdapterCount: $texAdapterCount")

    val dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null)
    val messageTextView = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dialog_message)

    // Log current textSecondCount value
    val currentCount = textSecondCount.text.toString()
    Log.d("SecondAdapter", "Current textSecondCount: $currentCount")

    // Ensure there's a space between the message and the count
    messageTextView.text = "Do you have apples $texAdapterCount?"

    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(dialogView)
        .setCancelable(true)

    val dialog = dialogBuilder.create()

    dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialog_button_positive).setOnClickListener {
        try {
            val currentCountInt = currentCount.toInt()
            if (currentCountInt >= texAdapterCount) {
                // Update textSecondCount and notify the change
                val newCount = currentCountInt - texAdapterCount
                textSecondCount.text = newCount.toString()

                // Save updated count to SharedPreferences
                val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                editor.putInt("textCount", newCount)
                editor.apply()

                // Notify the user
                showToast("Card unlocked successfully")

                // Send update broadcast
                if (context is Second) {
                    (context as Second).sendUpdateBroadcast(newCount)
                }
            } else {
                // Notify the user
                showToast("Not enough points to unlock")
            }

        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            Log.e("SecondAdapter", "Error parsing count: $e")
            showToast("Error processing the count")
        }
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialog_button_negative).setOnClickListener {
        // Handle negative button click
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    dialog.show()
}

private fun showToast(messsage: String) {
    Toast.makeText(context, messsage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

class CardViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val cardViewSecond: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewSecond)
    val textViewAdapter: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texAdapterCount)
}
}

So now when I click on YES button present in Alertdialog Subtraction takes place and I get a new value for textSecondCount and what I want is  value of my textCount should also get updated by the same value
I tried to broadcast the value to the MainActivity so that changes might reflect there too but the value of textCount doesn't change when value of textsecondCount changes.

By design you should assume activity that is not in the foreground is stopped and destroyed - touching its view directly is the last thing you want to do.

When subtraction takes place in dialog box , the value of Textview present in "Second" activity get's updated with new answer. At the same time I want my Textview present in MainActivity should also get updated with this new answer that Textview present in "Second" is updated with

You should make an object class with getters and setters to operate with the value. Then you operate with the value between activities, in each activity you save / load the value with the object that you have created.
Another option would be making everything in one activity with dialogs, and operate with a global variable to store the value within the class. There's more options but you should choose the approach that you wanna develop before making changes.
Hope I gave you some ideas!

I can't directly make everything in one activity because this scenario is in my main App project where I have two diffrent activities along with their own adapter classes , althougg I will look into object class

Can you show how your first suggestion could be done with a sample code?

I solved the issue by simply using Intent by passing the data back to MainActivity from second with the help of putInt and then receiving the data in MainActivity with the help of getInt and simply updating the Textview in MainActivity by it.

I'm glad you solved the issue. You should choose the other answer as the solution since it's the path that you followed and It worked out!

It seems you are trying to find a way to pass data between two activities.
IMO the simplest way to achieve this would be by using intent & onActivityResult apis.
I am assuming MainActivity opens first.
Follow these two steps to achieve your desired result.
#1 When you start "Second" activity from MainActivity, pass the count as intent extra and read it in "Second" activity.
Follow this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/14020692
#2 When you come back to MainActivity from "Second" activity pass the count back via setResult method.
Follow this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14785924/14020692

I am able to pass data from MainActivity to "Second" using Intent but When I update my TextView data in Second I am not able to pass that updated data to MainActivity and update the Textview present in MainActivity

Might be doing something wrong. Are you starting your Second activity via startActivityForResult api instead of startActivity?
As an alternative to #2, you can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66334160/14020692

Nope , I didn't use StartActivityFor Result, I initially took the updated newCount to Second Activity from Second Adapter and later I sent the newCount back to the MainActivity with Intent and in the MainActivity I created a update function and with the help of getInt method I took the value from Second Activity and updated with received value
